# unable to delete/update/select data from mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, centos

I'm running CentOS 6.5 and I can connect to mysql database via php but can not add/delete/update data. I can however update/add/delete data/tables via the terminal in mysql.

```
<?php

$mysqli = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', '', 'SA');
// Check connection

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
};


mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO Document(summary,text) Values ('summaryy test','random text');");


$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM Document");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['summary'];
  echo "<br>";
    };

?>
```

Comment: *"but can not add/delete/update data"* There's only an INSERT here. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` if you're not already doing so.

Comment: Plus, try removing the `;` at the end of both your `};`

Comment: do you have `mysqli` installed for php ?

Comment: so when I enable the errors, I get the following:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Unknown MySQL server host '127.0.0.1:3306' (3)' in /var/www/html/databasetest.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/databasetest.php(8): mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', '', 'SA') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/databasetest.php on line 8

Comment: Try removing the port number in `127.0.0.1:3306` or use `localhost`. I tested your code and it worked for me.

Comment: when I remove the ; I get a blank page with no content

Comment: So doing `$mysqli = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'SA');` or `$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'SA');` doesn't work?

Comment: I think you don't have a MySQL server installed or is not properly configured.

Comment: You're welcome. Which one worked?

Comment: removing the port # and just using the 127.0.0.1 as the address

Comment: Ok. I will post as an answer then you can click the tick/checkmark till it turns green, so we can properly close the question and mark as answered.

Comment: My answer has been posted below, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comment and to be marked as answered.

Solution:

Remove the port number `:3306` in

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', '', 'SA');
```

and do

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'SA');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
<?php

$mysqli = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', '', 'SA');
// Check connection

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
};


$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO Document(summary,text) Values ('summaryy test','random text')");


$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Document");

while($row = $mysqli->fetch_array()) {
  echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['summary'];
  echo "<br>";
    };

?>
```